# How to choose a different database for firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Currently I have a firebase function and a firebase.rc file looking like this:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "my-project-name"
  }
}
```

I have created a second (dev) database (not a new project). and I want to trigger the function from that

do I simply do:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "my-project-name-dev" (that is the name of my db)
  }
}
```

even though it's not the name of the project? I'm not sure how to switch db instances?

btw I'm using react native

Comment: I think may this "database": [
    {"target": "main", "rules": "foo.rules.json"},
    {"target": "other", "rules": "bar.rules.json"}
  ] will help you

Comment: for web we can use const app1 = firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://testapp-1234-1.firebaseio.com"
});

const app2 = firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://testapp-1234-2.firebaseio.com"
}, 'app2');

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases) of `.firebaserc` file (suppose you are referring to this) and I think this is not possible. The documentation mentions only projects aliases.

According to my understanding this approach assumes that you use different projects ex. for prod and for test. Using it you can change project not only database.

If you want to trigger from different database, but in the same project, you can add this to trigger by using `instance('INSTANCE_NAME')` ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_instance_and_path)) like:

```
functions.database.instance('my-app-db-2').ref('/foo/bar')
```